# Intel j3455 dummy sound issue snd intel

Tags: sound, laptop, intel

I can't hear audio from my laptop. Built in speakers and headphone jack aren't working. I can bring audio only through HDMI cable to the external display.

Output of `lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel`:

```
snd_hda_intel          53248  1 
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  4
snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_codec         147456  3
snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_core    94208  8
snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_pcm               118784  12
snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_ipc,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd                    94208  13
snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
```

Output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio`:

```
00:0e.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium
N4200/Atom E3900 Series Audio Cluster [8086:5a98] (rev 0d)
        Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Audio Cluster [10ec:111a]
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, snd_sof_pci
```

Output of `cat /proc/asound/car*/co* |  grep Codec`:

```
Codec: Intel Broxton HDMI
```

Alsa info txt with dmseg can be found down below:

http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=c7f1bbf64bc22d90eb7871fda26a8528aaecffaf

Let me know possible solution for this problem?
If you think BIOS options might solve the problem, let me know which option do you have in mind?